# How to extract column in text file in bash

Tags: bash, text, awk

I have a text file, the format is below, and I would like to only capture the numbers after the `.txt`. I did `awk '{print $2}' filename` and it gave me the wrong result.

For some of the lines, it gave me `:` instead of the number. For example, in the second line I will get `:` instead of `914`.

Is there any other way that I can extract the numbers after `.txt`? I am not referring to numbers in the `rgb`part.

```
image/Subject01.txt:1310 : image/Subject01/Scene4/Color/rgb7
image/Subject01.txt: 914 : image/Subject01/Scene4/Color/rgb3
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot specifying a custom field separator. Like

```
awk -F ' *: *' '{print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/\.txt:[^:]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",val)
  print val
}
' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using field separator.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[.:]"} $2=="txt"{print $3+0}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the cut command

```
cut -d ':' -f 2 filename
```

This will set the [d]elimiter to [:] and then will take the [2]nd [f]ield

Comment: By this you get also spaces instead only the number itself. I would perform this: cut -d ':' -f 2 xxx | sed -e "s/ //g". I like your solution much, because tools like cut and sed have a lower memory footprint compared to gawk which has a big amount of capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GNU grep for this:

```
$ grep -Po '\.txt: *\K[[:digit:]]+' infile
1310
914
```

`-P` enables Perl-compatible regular expressions (required for the `\K`), and `-o` retains only the match.

The regular expression looks for the string `.txt:`, followed by any number of blanks (including zero); this part of the match is discarded (`\K`), and then we match as many digits as we can find.